# Data Validation in Apps Script (Between Two Numbers)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to set a cell's data validation to be between two numbers namely, 1 and the balance of items in a budget.  It keeps giving the following error:

> Oct 12, 2022, 9:41:14 PM Error Exception: The parameters
> (number,String) don't match the method signature for
> SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationBuilder.requireNumberBetween.
> at applyQtyValidation(Code:242:8)
> at getQtyValidationData(Code:233:3)
> at onEdit(Code:59:7)

Please help...

```
//Global variables    
var reqSheetName = "Material Requisition";

var colStructure = 1;

var colComponent = 2;

var colWorks = 3;

var colItem = 4;

var colQty = 5;

var colUnit = 6;

var colBalance = 7;

var colBudgetCode = 8;

var colDuplicate = 18;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var wsBudget = ss.getSheetByName("Budget");

var wsRequisition = ss.getSheetByName(reqSheetName);

var rawData = wsBudget.getRange(5, 1, wsBudget.getLastRow(), 7).getValues();

var arrDetails = [];

function onEdit(e) {

  //variables needed
  var editedCell = e.range;
  var sheetName = editedCell.getSheet().getName();

  var r = editedCell.getRow();
  var c = editedCell.getColumn();
  var valFilter = editedCell.getValue();

  //Set order qty
  if (sheetName === reqSheetName && c === colItem && r > 11) {

    getQtyValidationData(r);
  }
}


function getQtyValidationData(r) {

  var minQty = 1;
  var maxQty = wsRequisition.getRange(r, colBalance).getValue();
  var cell = wsRequisition.getRange(r, colQty).getA1Notation();

  applyQtyValidation(minQty, maxQty, cell);
}


function applyQtyValidation(minQty, maxQty, cell) {

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
    .newDataValidation()
    .requireNumberBetween(minQty, maxQty)
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .setHelpText("Select a number between " + minQty + " and " + maxQty)
    .build();

  wsRequisition.getRange(cell).setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 11) {
    e.source.toast('Gate1');
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5).clearDataValidations();
    var maxQty = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 7).getValue();
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireNumberBetween(1, maxQty).setHelpText(`Select a number between 1 and ${maxQty}`).setAllowInvalid(true).build();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5).setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

[image]

I would have preferred to do it like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 11) {
    e.source.toast('Gate1');
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5).clearDataValidations();
    var maxQty = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 7).getValue();
    let list = [...Array.from(new Array(maxQty).keys(),x => String(Number(x+1)))];
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(list));
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setHelpText(`Select a number between 1 and ${maxQty}`).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5).setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Cooper! Both options are working but I will use your first, less preferred option because the maxQty can sometimes be in the hundreds.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points to vote for your response :-(